# difference between ($in) and just (in) mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

What is the difference between ($in) and just (in) mongoose? Why we use $ Sign. Sometimes I see $in and sometimes just in query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in functionality there is no difference. we use **$** sign because if we don't write it, mongodb consider it as a string. By the way according to mongodb documentation the **$** sign reserved for operators.

Comment: So what are you saying? There's no difference, but `in` is a string and `$in` is an operator?

Comment: I said there is no difference between **$in** and **.in()** operators. we're using $ sign prefix to show an operator in mongo db if we just write **in**, mongo db consider it as a string. 
pay attention I wrote **in** word  not .in() or $in.

Comment: You didn't say there's no difference between `$in` and `.in()`. Your answer could be misconstrued by people thinking that `{ field : { $in : [ ... ] } }` and `{ field : { in : [ ... ] } }` are the same.

Comment: I think you must edit your subject what is **in** word? is **in** a function in mongoose or a string or an operator. It's ok to ask question but you must clearify what is **in** . anyway, I think you got your answer. good luck